# Java analog for PHP's StdClass

Tags: java, php, jsf, jakarta-ee

I need something like a property bag to throw key value pairs into.
I want to create list of such objects, initialize them in bean and then use the list to render table in JSF template.
I know how to do it, but I want to avoid creating some special class for that case, like `OrderLineItem` and using `List<OrderLineItem>`.
I do not want to define new class.

In PHP I could use StdClass.
StdClass is a sparsely documented class in PHP which has no predefined members.

```
$object = new StdClass;
$object->foo = 'bar';
```

But, as far as I know, Primefaces `<p:dataTable>` list item must be an object with getter.
If I want to reference `<h:outputText value="#{item.title}" />`, my list object should have `getTitle()` method.

Is there any walkaround in my case or I really need to define special class to make life easier?
Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with defining a new class?

Comment: @BartFriederichs It will be used only once..

Comment: that doesn't seem like a valid reason. Classes are there exactly for what you want to do. Why break the OO paradigm? Besides, the class you'd use now is also used only once.

Comment: It would be better if you add the functional requirement in order to get a decent answer. I don't think using a `Map<String, String>` will fulfill your needs, maybe it will do just for this problem.

Comment: The functional requirement is clear if you understand what PHP's StdClass does. Did anyone come up with a good solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want a simple key/value table, then the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) might be what you are looking for.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

myMap.put("foo", "bar");

System.out.println(myMap.get("foo")); // outputs "bar"
```

This example matches Strings to Strings, but you can use HashMaps to map any type to any other type. You can even create a `Map<Object, Object>` to create a weakly-typed map which maps anything to anything. But for most use-cases you would rather use a more specialized form.

Comment: Will `#{item.foo}` in JSF template output `bar` ?

Comment: @BogdanBurim it would be `#{yourManagedBean.yourMap['key']}`

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a `Map`.

You can store key-value pairs in it pretty easy:

```
Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> myMap = new HashMap<KeyClass, ValueClass>();
```

Use the `put` method to put data in it. If you use simple `String` values it will be like this:

```
myMap.put("key", "value");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood you well. But I think you mean SelectItem or JsfMap.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use an anonymous class:

```
return new HashMap<String, String>() {
  {
    this.put("key", "value");
  }
};
```